# read xml with java e mapper in json with objectmapper

Tags: java, xml, json

I have this question for your.
I've a simple file xml and I have to convert it to file Json. So far that's all right but, the output that gives me back isn't well formatted. 
Here is the code:
**modalities.xml**

```
<cons>
    <modalities type="mod">
        <modality id="001">
            <name>CC</name>
        </modality>
        <modality id="002">
            <name>RS</name>
        </modality>
        <modality id="003">
            <name>TC</name>
        </modality>
        <modality id="004">
            <name>US</name>
        </modality>
   </modalities>
```

And **ListModalities.java**

```
{ ...
 String path = "modalities.xml";
        ModalitiesMapperImpXml modXml = new ModalitiesMapperImpXml();
        if (modality.equals("list")) 
            modXml.load(path); //The method return the list that contain the name of modality ( CC - US )
    try {
        ObjectMapper mp = new ObjectMapper();
        return mp.writeValueAsString(modXml);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            return jpe.getMessage();
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"modalities":[{"value":"\n\t\t\n\t\t\tCC\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tRS\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t}]}
```

how can I delete the spaces and the tab character?
Can you help me? Thanks

Regard 
Vit

Comment: You need to show how you read the xml. ModalitiesMapperImpXml.java?

Comment: public void readListModality() {
  try {
   SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
   Document doc = builder.build(new File(pathfile));
   Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();
   List children = rootElement.getChildren("modalities");
   Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Element element = (Element)iterator.next();
    Modalities mod1 = new Modalities();
    mod1.setValue(element.getValue());
    this.addItem(mod1);
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Problem is how you iterate over the XML:

```
element.getNodeValue()
```

should be replaced by

```
element.getTextContent()
```

Comment: Which Element class are you using? I assumed it would be org.w3.dom.Element.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for the late, I've resolved the problem using the interface Node,